# Regex substitution with Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with several lines like these ones:

```
cd_cod_bus
nm_number_ex
cd_goal
```

And I want to get rid of the `-` and uppercase the following character using Notepad++ (I can also use other tool but if it doesn't get the problem more troublesome).

So I tried to get the characters with the following regex `(?<=_)\w` and replace it using `\U\1\E\2` for the uppercasing trick but here is where my problems came. I think the regex is OK but once I click replace all I get this result:

```
cd_od_us
nm_umber_x
cd_oal
```

as you can see it is only deleting the match.

Do you know where the problem is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The search regex has no capture groups, i.e. the \1 and \2 references in the replacement do not refer to anything.

Try this instead:

```
Search: _(\w)
Replace \U\1\E
```

There you have a capture group in the search part (the parenthesis around the \w) and the \1 in the replacement refers back to what was captured.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
_(.)
```

with

```
\U$1
```

will give you:

```
cdCodBus
nmNumberEx
cdGoal
```

and for your

> I can also use other tool but if it doesn't get the problem more troublesome

I suggest you try vim.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
_(\w)
```

and replace with

```
\U\1
```

[here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dLrt.jpg)